# Magento: How do I get a list of categories from a product collection?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

On a certain pages I have a large product collection with products of multiple categories. How do I get a list of categories that are included in the currently loaded product collection?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of another way other than iterating over the collection and keeping track of the categories of each product. Something like this:

```
$categories = [];
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $categories[] =  $product->getCategory();
}
// To get rid of the duplicates
$categories = array_unique($categories);
```

Answer (score -1):

This way you get the individual product categories, and you can mount the array as it sees best

```
<?php
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach($categoryIds as $catId){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
    }
?>
```